# Angular 9 disabled button when nothing is selected in dropdown list

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to enable/disable a button in Angular 9 when a dropdown list is not selected.

dashboard.html.ts :

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputCollaborateur">Collaborateur</label>
     <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="edit.collaborateur" id="inputCollaborateur" name="inputCollaborateur" required>
          <option *ngFor='let collaborateur of collaborateurs' [ngValue]="collaborateur">{{collaborateur.matricule}} - {{collaborateur.nom}} {{collaborateur.prenom}}</option>
     </select>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="enregistrerCreation()">Ajouter</button>
```

I tried using this in the button code `ng-disabled="!edit.collaborateur` but it doesn't work...

Comment: By "not selected", do you mean the dropdown shows the first value from `collaborateurs`?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!edit.collaborateur" (click)="enregistrerCreation()">Ajouter</button>
```

Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Add template reference variable on select element and assign ngControl as follow.
Then use template reference variable to check the validation of input.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputCollaborateur">Collaborateur</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="edit.collaborateur" id="inputCollaborateur" name="inputCollaborateur" required #collaboreurRef="ngModel">
          <option *ngFor='let collaborateur of collaborateurs' [ngValue]="collaborateur">{{collaborateur.matricule}} - {{collaborateur.nom}} {{collaborateur.prenom}}</option>
        </select>
  </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="collaboreurRef.invalid" (click)="enregistrerCreation()" >Ajouter</button>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it doesn't disabled the button ....

Comment: I would like to but complicated with all the thing and code i have in the files and I never created one ....

Comment: I have tried in this stackblitz it's working fine:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-driven-forms-select-option-vfenk8

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-61bahu here's mine but lots of error due to librairy

Comment: it work with you because you put a function compareFn. if i delete it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Having compare function is  recommended if you are using object assigning to value attribute, https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selectionr

Comment: ok, i did the same but still having the button always enable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216482/discussion-between-chellappan--and-issou).

Comment: i feel it's because you have not dynamic data. my ' [(ngModel)]="edit.collaborateur" ' and ' [ngValue]="collaborateur" ' so how can I match it with your country2 in your exemple ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="(!edit.collaborateur || edit.collaborateur === '' )" 
 (click)="enregistrerCreation()">Ajouter</button>
```

Comment: Or you can try to check data with (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" in html and then check the enable/disable in TS file

Comment: have u got an exemple for the '  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event) ' ?

Comment: I think you have a problem somewhere else in the code because one of these methods had to work . Do you have an example of these code ?

Comment: Try this too 
[disabled]="(collaboreurRef.invalid || !edit.collaborateur || edit.collaborateur === '')"


Otherwise you should review your code if all the data arrives correctly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply put a check to select tag. You can use the change event handler for that case.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputCollaborateur">Collaborateur</label>
     <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="edit.collaborateur" id="inputCollaborateur" name="inputCollaborateur" (change)="check_for_disable()" required>
          <option *ngFor='let collaborateur of collaborateurs' [ngValue]="collaborateur">{{collaborateur.matricule}} - {{collaborateur.nom}} {{collaborateur.prenom}}</option>
     </select>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="enregistrerCreation()" [disabled]="disabled">Ajouter</button>
```

function in ts file

```
disabled:boolean = true;


ngOnInit() {
    check_for_disable();
}


check_for_disable() {
    if(this.edit?.collaborateur !== "") this.disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an onchange event to the select.

```js
function enableButton()
{
    var selectelem = document.getElementById('corpusname');
    var btnelem = document.getElementById('seedoc');
    btnelem.disabled = !selectelem.value;
}
```

```html
<select class='corpusname' id='corpusname' size='1' name='corpusname' required onchange="enableButton()"/>
<option value=''>Select a corpus</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="seedoc" disabled value="Submit">
```